# Can we create android app using cordova and visual studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2013

Can we create a mobile app using cordova and visual studio 2013?

Thank you

Comment: Yes. But it has nothing to do with xamarin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using VS2013 Update 5.  Links here - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675 to install tools.  An overview of the tools is here - https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs .

Getting started with Cordova on VS documentation is here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545(v=vs.140).aspx .

I personally recommend you move up to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.  Its free and is just as powerful as Visaul Studio Pro, except for some team testing issues.

This is a fantastic tool  Watch for more announcements on it in the future.

Healy in Tampa

Comment: Thank you so much joe !!.  :-)